# Unable to locate Python3 -vevn | Rasberry Pi 1

Tags: python

Raspberry Pi 1 B+ Model

I was trying to install Google Assistant in Raspberry Pi 1.is error - 
I need to install python3 - vevn 
To which I get the error -

```
E:Unable to locate package python3-v3evn
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You likely mean [`python3-venv`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3-venv), **not `python3-vevn`**. 'Venv' stands for **v**irtual **env**ironment, so it's not surprising that `python3-vevn` isn't found. The correct command is:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

If the steps you're following are incorrect and do say **vevn**, you should let them know. If you've just misread the package name, you can just install the correct package and continue without any issues.